# In Android, how to change the title of a different MenuItem inside onOptionsItemSelected()

Tags: android

On clicking a certain MenuItem in a Options Menu in Android, I need to change the title of a different MenuItem in the same Menu. What is the way to do this?

When a MenuItem in an options menu is clicked, onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem) is called.
You can change the title of the MenuItem which is passed as a parameter in the 
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem), but not of any other MenuItem. I need to know how to change the title of a MenuItem that is not passed as parameter to onOptionsItemSelected(), but which belongs to the same Menu.

I did not find a way to get handle to containing Menu inside the onOptionsItemSelected method (which is called when any MenuItem is clicked).

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Android Dev Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

> **Changing the menu when it opens**
>
> The `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method is called only the first time the Options Menu is opened. The system keeps and re-uses the Menu you define in this method until your Activity is destroyed. If you want to change the Options Menu each time it opens, you must override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. This passes you the `Menu` object as it currently exists. This is useful if you'd like to remove, add, disable, or enable menu items depending on the current state of your application.
>
> Note: You should never change items in the Options Menu based on the View currently in focus. When in touch mode (when the user is not using a trackball or d-pad), Views cannot take focus, so you should never use focus as the basis for modifying items in the Options Menu. If you want to provide menu items that are context-sensitive to a View, use a Context Menu.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.photoviewer_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.photoviewer_menu_button);
    item.setTitle("title");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This wil work for sure try it............

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.addappointmentmenu, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.add_appontment_menu).setTitle("Add Appointment");
    //Similarly set for all your menu's has above

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can change the title, but you could remove the item and then add another one back in with the same ID with a different title.

```
    Menu foo;
    foo.removeItem(id);
    foo.add(0, id, 0, R.string.a_new_title);
```

Answer (score 2):

But when `MenuItem` is more than six times in the `Menu` resource and if you click on menu then `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called either once or twice.

- With a simple click on menu then the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called only once
- When you click on menu and then click on the "More" option i.e. sixth option then `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called twice.

I hope this will help someone.