# How can I change MenuItem's title programatically inside NavigationView?

Tags: java, android

I successfully implemented in my app a "side menu" with NavigationView and creating a custom ActionBar, following the instructions within [this tutorial](https://danielme-com.translate.goog/2018/12/19/diseno-android-menu-lateral-con-navigation-drawer/amp/?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp). It looks like this:

[image]

That's great, it works... it opens by "hamburger" button in ActionBar and by sliding finger left to right; I can attach functionality to those options. **But, I'd like to change options title dinamically**, by Java. About that, I found [some other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4127132/3692177) and tried implementing the solution in the answer. The result was... unexpected, but curious:

I override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem option3 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_option3);
    option3.setTitle("Option3 -> " + option3_cnt + " elements");
    MenuItem option4 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_option4);
    option4.setTitle("Option4 -> " + option4_cnt + " elements");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

What this actually did, was creating a copy of the `NavigationView` menu, but in a "three-dot button" at the right side of ActionBar (that button wasn't there before implementing `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, BTW). And yes, it shows the counters; but the idea was doing exactly that thing, but with the "side menu" of the NavigationView, instead of that old-fashioned "options menu". How can I achieve that?

By the way, `MenuItem`s have a XML structure like this within `main_menu.xml`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_option3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:title="Option3" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_option4"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:title="Option4" />
```

I'd like, perhaps, to add more elements to the `MenuItem`s themselves; so I could place the counter in some kind of "custom layout" attached to the `MenuItem` or something like that... but for now, I conform with attaching the count to the title itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the menu from `NavigationView` & do the `findItem` to get access to `MenuItem` which then you can use to `setTitle`.

**Example:**

```
    // your navigationView
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    
    // item you want to change, choose your id here
    MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery);
    menuItem.setTitle("Changed at runtime");
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried something similar before implementing the referenced question's main answer; but I failed because I did `MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_gallery);`. So, I had to do `getMenu().findItem()` instead... thanks